# Trying to get a div draggable from information pulled from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

Hi I have a `div` with the following styling:

```
#lists li {
    width: 580px;
    background: #FFD586;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size: x-large;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

I want to make the `div` draggable, however the content within the `div` is being pulled in from my database, and I cannot seem to get the content to be draggable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your content coming from a database shouldnt cause ant problems. As long as it is in the draggable `div` it will work. Look into using jQueryUI draggable if you want to make divs draggable.

Comment: So what exactly is the error/problem? Are you using jQuery Ui Draggable? Are you trying to write a plugin on your own? ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give that list element class name or use id and make it draggable, here the jquery code:

```
$( ".draggableclass").draggable(); //$( "#yourid").draggable();

$( ".droppableclass" ).droppable({ //same here
    accept:".draggableclass",
    drop: function( event, ui ) { //function that will activate after dropping
}
});
```

If you don't need droppable function, just use draggable and you'll be able to drag it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try Jquery, it's easy to use, see more here:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lists').draggable();
});
```

Or see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9axcg/

Comment: Not really worthy of an answer... Could have just left a comment.